# python doctest failure error

Tags: python, doctest

I am trying to run doctest on this code and this is the error I am getting. Can anyone explain what exactly is missing in the syntax, since the expected and got results are the same.

Doctest:

```
"""
>>> d.display()
Inorder traversal keys
2 3 4 5 9 10
Preorder traversal keys
4 3 2 9 5 10
Postorder traversal keys
2 3 5 10 9 4
"""
```

Failure result:

```
Failed example:
d.display()
Expected:
Inorder traversal keys
2 3 4 5 9 10
Preorder traversal keys
4 3 2 9 5 10
Postorder traversal keys
2 3 5 10 9 4
Got:
Inorder traversal keys
2 3 4 5 9 10 
Preorder traversal keys
4 3 2 9 5 10 
Postorder traversal keys
2 3 5 10 9 4
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   9 in __main__.BinarySearchTreeDict
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Double-check the whitespace - `doctest` is a bit picky about that sort of thing

Comment: I checked the whitespaces, even tried copy pasting the same code as the output. Not working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an extra whitespace in your `display()` function for  Inorder traversal keys
and Preorder traversal keys . (Found this by manually highlighting each  line separately in the `Expected` and `Got` sections of failure result)

```
2 3 4 5 9 10 # has an extra whitespace

4 3 2 9 5 10 # has an extra whitespace
```